# Manual Column resize and context menu in handsOnTable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, handsontable

I have created a simple Spreadsheet with `HandsOnTable`. Followed doc and tried to `manualResizeCol` and add `contextMenu` but it is not working. sample attached.

And also why am I getting below mentioned warning when using `<HotTable />` component.

> Using UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code.

[Code Sandbox HandsOnTable](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cherry-0g8lkx?file=/src/Grid.tsx)

```
<HotTable
    width="100%"
    height="auto"
    data={d}
    ref={(el) => (hotRef.current[index] = el!)}
    stretchH="all"
    rowHeaders={true}
    colHeaders={true}
    minSpareCols={36}
    maxCols={40}
    manualColumnResize={true}
    cells={(row: number) => {
      if (row === 0) {
       return {
         readOnly: true,
         className: "header-cell"
         };
      } else return { readOnly: false };
     }}
    contextMenu={["remove_col", "remove_row"]}
    licenseKey="non-commercial-and-evaluation" // for non-commercial use only
 />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to React 18 and CodeSandbox. We are noticing that, in this case, plugins don't work. If you try the same code in a different sandbox or locally with the same configuration it will work fine.

You need to add this to your main app file:

```
import { registerAllModules } from 'handsontable/registry'; 

registerAllModules();
```

Comment: on local machine its not working also. `"react": "^18.2.0",`

Comment: ran the code on Replit, still getting same result.

Comment: I noticed that you are not importing and registering the modules that are required. You need to add this to your main app file:

import { registerAllModules } from 'handsontable/registry';

// register Handsontable's modules
registerAllModules();

It won't solve problem in codesandbox, but it should now work correctly in other sandboxes and locally. Here's an example in jsFiddle with React 18 and Handsontable 12.1.3

https://jsfiddle.net/aszymanski/quo9b0en/1/

Comment: It did worked as you mentioned. but I am wondering why there is no mentioning of `registerAllmodules` in  Docs getting started?? you can update the answer I will mark it.

Comment: further can you tell me why am getting warning about unsafe_ComponentDidMount as i mentioned in question?

Comment: I'm glad it worked, I edited my answer. As for your suggestion, I agree. I already suggested that change in our documentation.

About that warning, we will look into this and see what might be causing it.

Comment: I'm using HOT 12.3.1 with React 18.2.0 with Vite and I confirm that your solution doesn't work, I still have the *UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate* error